# Python POST web request with file input form

Tags: python, post, geocoding, webrequest

I have quite a few addresses that I need to geocode (find latitude and longitude). US Census Bureau offers such a service at the following link: [US Census Geocoder](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch?form), which limits at 1000 addresses per request. Right now I have to do it manually over and over again. I am learning Python and I would love to find out how to do it automatically. What packages should I use and how can I specify an input file, which on the website requires me to click the button "Choose File" and then select a file?

EDIT:
The webpage with Google Chrome developer tools is shown below:
[image]

As you can see, there are not many fields to fill. The form is described as:

```
<form method="POST" action="addressbatch" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select Address File :</label>
    <input type="file", name="addressFile", required="required">
    ...
    <div id="_f_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult_benchmark_id">...</div>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Get Results">
</form>
```

I've looked at the requests package and gave it a try. Here is what I have been able to do:

```
url = 'http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch?form'
payload = {'name': 'addressFile', 'filename':'C:/ds/data/california/census_geocode/batch_0.csv'}
session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

The result is `r=<Response [400]`, or a Bad Request. I am not sure how to specify the submission of the request as the source only has type and value fields, no name field.

Used Google developer tools to track the request, here is what I got:

```
Request Payload:

------WebKitFormBoundaryINe95Tc7sF0LHtgj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addressFile"; filename="batch_0.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundaryINe95Tc7sF0LHtgj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="benchmark"

4
------WebKitFormBoundaryINe95Tc7sF0LHtgj--
```

I am still not sure how to use this information in my request though.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the page's source code, the request which is being made is a POST. I would suggest you to take a look at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html. Also, at the developer tools of your browser, take a look at the call which is made on the **Get Result** button.

Comment: I've updated my question and showed what I have been able to find out so far. Obviously it is still not resolved yet.